# PIG: more combined input paths than input paths?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera

After executing PIG scripts, I have regularly such description in logs:

```
Total input paths to process : 101
Total input paths (combined) to process : 1414
```

How it is possible to have less input path that combined one ?

Comment: Pig uses hadoop split strategy to split files (virtual split) according to block size (64 mb or 128 mb by default). Your input file size seems to be bigger thats why PIG used split to provide split offset of input file to each mapper. Read about pig.maxCombinedSplitSize and pig.minCombinedSplitSize to get more details

Comment: Could be due to the number of maps. Did you have 14 map tasks?